# Unique matrix satisfying a system of equations

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control

Assume I have a $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $G$ of rank $p$ satisfying a set of $np - p(p-1)/2$ equations $v^T_jGv_j = 1$, $j = 1 \ldots np - p(p-1)/2$ for some given vectors $v_j$. It is assumed these equations are linearly independent. Note here that the number of equations is exactly equal to the degrees of freedom in $G$. Is it then true that there are only finitely many matrices $G$ satisfying these equations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking whether a non degenerate system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns has a finite number of solutions? The answer is "yes", and one can sharpen the result to "a unique solution".


Comment: @Igor. This is not a linear system, unless $p=0$. There is the nonlinear constraint that $G$ has rank $p$.

Comment: @Igor. Just try the case $n=2$ and $p=1$. You'll find two solutions.

Comment: Also, isn't it the case that there are potentially infinitely many solutions in the case that the entries come from a skew field?  The poster has not made it clear from where the matrix entries come.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.02

Comment: AH, I have missed the rank constraint.

Comment: The entries in the matrix are from the real numbers. 
One could view this as an equation $Ax = 1$, where the distinct elements from $G$ are in the vector $x$ and the $j:th$ row in $A$ contains the distinct elements from the matrix $2v_jv_j^T - diag(v_jv_j^T)$. Because of the rank constraint, the elements in $x$ are dependent. We can write them as $\sqrt{g_{ii}g_{jj}}\cos(\alpha_{ij})$ where some $\alpha_{ij} = \alpha_i - \alpha_j$,i.e., some depend on the other angles. So the question is whether any $np - p(p-1)/2$ equations are enough to either get a finite number solutions or no solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case $n=3$,$p=2$, your 5 constraints for $v_1 = (1,0,0)^T$, $v_2 = (0,1,0)^T$, $v_3 = (0,0,1)^T$, $v_4 = (1,-2,0)^T$ and $v_5 = (1,-1,1)^T$ have solution $G = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & t\cr
1 & 1 & t\cr t & t & 1\cr}$, which has rank 2 and is positive semidefinite if $-1 < t < 1$.

Comment: How did you arrive at this solution?  I guess I really mean: where did v4 and v5 come from?

Comment: Using Maple, I looked for $v_4 = (a,b,0)^T$, $v_5 = (c,d,e)^T$ for which the determinant of a symmetric solution $G$ is identically 0.